# What is the difference between "in" and "within"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

It seems they can be used interchangeably but I am not sure. Can somebody explain the difference of use between these two key words? Where do they become different?

Comment: You certainly can't use them interchangeably in all contexts - **in** can be used in many places where **within** is totally wrong. If OP is unsure, I suggest sticking to **in**, which would rarely if ever be unacceptable.

Comment: Many of my high school students (I am a History teacher) like to use "within" in places where "in" would do, because they think "within" sounds more scholarly. So I get essays with titles like "Authoritarianism Within Putin's Russia" or "Communist Economic Policies Within Cuba." The use of "within" in these titles makes it sound as if authoritarianism and communist policies are physical things that somehow float around inside the borders of those respective countries. So I encourage students to use "in" whenever it makes sense. (But it's difficult to convince a young, ambitious student to use

Comment: ...a small word in place of a longer word!) @Alex

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Within** is closer to *inside* - it mainly refers to something like a building where you are physically in (or inside).

**In** can also mean a state or an organisation, so you can be "in trouble", or "in school" but not "within trouble".

Comment: The other answer makes a good point too: You can't always substitute _in_ for _within_ (or _inside_).

Comment: @mgb What about the example sentence "the algorithm is able to detect people in/within google-earth images"? Is *within* acceptable/preferable in this case?

Comment: @halirutan, no 'within an image' wouldn't be normal, Generally always use 'in' unless you know different.

Comment: @mgb, For <within> vs <inside>?

Answer (score 6):

**In**- A limit of some sort.

> i.e. "In 6 days,..."
>
> > *You limit the time in the sentence exactly.*

**Within**- Inside the said limit.

> i.e. "Within 6 days,..."
>
> > *You limit the time in the sentence, but inside the said time.*

Answer (score -4):

where ever there is a certainty we use in and in uncertainty we use within.

> I will come in next week. - Use IN-
>            I will come within this week - Use within

Also, if some timeframe is allocated ie : do the work in ten minutes

Then if the work is completed in 10 min then use in and if completed before 10 min then within.

Comment: *I will come in next week* does not mean (what I surmise you are trying for) "I will come in the next week".  "I will come within the week" means the latter, but the way to express your last point is "I will come in a week's time".